# Get "No Service" on Android Emulator

Tags: android

Android newbie. I am writing up a simple Google Maps application but when I start up my Android Emulator, it displays the "No Service" message, and I am unable to see the actual map. A couple of days ago everything was working fine, and I was able to connect. Didn't really make a change that could affect this.

Any idea about what might be going on?

Comment: What kind of connection are you using ? WiFi or Ethernet ?

Answer (score 1):

The emulator attempts, somehow, to sniff on an Internet connection on startup. If it does not find something it likes, it pretends to be in offline mode. You can tell this from the signal strength icon -- instead of the normal two bars, you get zero bars and an X.

Just restart the emulator, and you will probably get your connection on the second try.

Comment: Yea, its showing the X instead of bars. Tried restarting a few times, same result.

Comment: @floatingfrisbee: Hmmm...got any unusual firewalls or proxies or anything on your office network? Is the PC hosting the emulator particularly slow? Normally, the connection check works fine, and I've never had it fail twice in succession when I legitimately had a connection.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact problem tonight.  My research showed that the emulator tries to connect to the first network adapter it can find.  Success or failure is all based on that first adapter.  For me, I had a VPN with a name that started with A.  I renamed it to "VPN" so that it was below the "Local Network" adapter, restarted the emulator and voila! it worked.

Silly? Yes. Stupid? Yes. Works? Yep.