# Android Emulator 'No Service'

Tags: android-emulator

I am new to both the android and android development so I'm not on familiar ground here.

When I start the emulator I have no service. Therefore I have no internet connection on the emulator.

I am running Windows 7 and I generally run the emulator via eclipse. 
My host machine is connected to the internet via the Local Area Network. There is no proxy.

I have tried:

- Disabling all network adapters except for the Local Area Network [[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098923/get-no-service-on-android-emulator)]
- Running the emulator from cmd line with: emulator -avd -dns-server 8.8.8.8
- Reinstalling the SDK Tools 9 and Platform Tools (rev 2).
- Restarting the machine! :P

Is there a setup needed to specify to simulate a 3G connection? Or could this be a Windows 7 permissions issue? Or am I doomed like these folks: [link](http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f4/no-internet-connectivity-emulator-35883/) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376553/upgraded-to-sdk-2-3-now-no-emulators-have-connectivity)

Comment: Glad to see you solved your issue, but I would suggest posting the solution as an answer to this question. As it is currently, your question (the title notwithstanding) may appear to others to be unanswered.

Comment: @jason: Will do.. Was unfamiliar with the UI for SO.

Comment: Cool. Welcome to SO, by the way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah! found the solution.. I uninstalled the entire SDK and reinstalled it to C:/Android. I deleted the C:/Users/[your-name]/.android folder and recreated an avd. Voila.. Something in there worked!

**[edit]**
Actually it looks like you have to keep restarting the emulator until it connects. I will often get no service so I restart a bunch of times till it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found that 'Airplane Mode' was enabled by default in the standalone android emulator - this may also be the cause in the sdk version. Turning this off (by holding down the red power button until the menu came up, and then toggling the airplane mode button/section) allowed the emulator to 'find service' and connect properly through the LAN.